# When does the solution to the Fokker-Planck equation admit a density?

Tags: probability-distributions, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

Given a Markov process $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ on $(\mathbb R^n, \mathcal B_{\mathbb R^n})$, under which conditions does the solution to the Fokker-Planck equation

$$\frac{\partial u(t,x)}{\partial t}= \mathcal L^* u(t,x)$$

admit a density with respect to the Lebesgue measure?

I am particularly interested in the case where $X_t$ is a diffusion process, but I would prefer a general answer if that exists. In the diffusion case, the condition might be something along ellipticity or uniform ellipticity. A reference would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hypoellipticity seems to be the case where the solution has a smooth density wrt Lebesgue measure. So a requirement for a density should be weaker.